# Conduktor filter on a specific value to be not null

Tags: filter, apache-kafka, notnull, conduktor

I am trying to use Conduktor to filter records on a kafka topic, where a specific value is not null.

Here, using the Advanced - Field Selection filter, I can filter Brand Names being null using Value:

**.billingAccounts[0].clientContracts[0].brandName
null**

[image]

or I can filter on a specific brandName, e.g. BrandABC:

**.billingAccounts[0].clientContracts[0].brandName
BrandABC**

[image]

However, I am having trouble filtering on all records where brandName isn't null.

Any help?